# Playstation 1 games stretched outside screen

Tags: monitor, ps1

I got my PlayStation 1 setup with an RCA cable with a SCART adaptor.

When I play games they don't fit inside the screen - they appear to be 'stretched' off of the screen and I can only see the middle of the image. This makes it extremely hard to see what I'm doing.

Does anybody know a solution to this problem?

Specs:

- [Full tv specs Philips 22PFH4000/88, 4000-Series](http://www.philips.co.uk/c-p/22PFH4000_88/4000-series-full-hd-slim-led-tv-with-digital-crystal-clear/specifications)
- PlayStation 1 model is 'scph-9001 B'

Answer (score 1):

It turned out, that the monitor settings were set to `16:9`.

After correction of the settings, the image was ok.